# Mail is not being sent due to @ symbol in the message

Tags: php, email, drupal, drupal-7

I am stuck into a problem from hours which has occurred due to @ symbol in message while sending an email. Does anyone know how to resolve this, It may save mine a lot of time. following is my code

```
$message .= '<p> '.$gift_card->field_from_name["und"][0]["value"].' has sent you a gift card </p>';
```

where `$gift_card->field_from_name["und"][0]["value"]` returns email id ( which contains @ sign ) and when I remove this line from complete message it works properly

Comment: check your phpinfo to see if sendmail is correctly configured i.e (sendmail_path) in your php.ini file

Comment: i'm not sure about my answer. Once try it by using mysqli_real_escape_string($con,$gift_card->field_from_name["und"][0]["value"] ) instead of directly sending.

Answer (score 1):

use this code-

```
$message .= "<p> '".$gift_card->field_from_name["und"][0]["value"]."' has sent you a gift card </p>";
```